# prevention of data truncation or growth in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have **SSRS** **report** where there are 8 to 9 tablix columns and **they have occupied all the width** -(standard width for A4 size) and now there is a situation where some of the column will have net total values for money which increases beyond the length of the field like this.

[image]

I want it to be displayed in one line. It should print 99 in one line only. Hence I changed the length of the field and result is as below, where I can see all things displayed in one line but while printing it generates extra data in new page because it has grown beyond page size.

[image]

I also tried to stop the growth by changing CanGrow property but that truncates the data as below.

[image]

Can someone help me here? What should be the approach to do that. Report is fully utilized (width wise) and none of the column can be re-adjusted. If adjusted, it is going to break print functionality.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't resize any of the columns (like the 72% column - why is that so wide?) to make the problem column bigger, then there are not too many options to fix this...  You could do one of the following:

1. Set the padding on the cells to 0pt (at least on the left and right), which will allow a little more data to fit in the field
2. Decrease the font size, which will also allow a little more data to fit in the field
3. Decrease the margins on Report Properties so you can make the columns a little bigger

Comment: I re-adjusted the columns to accommodate the data and it seems to be working now. Thank for the options.

Answer (score 0):

Well about the cangrow setting, and why that caused SSRS to truncate your column, that's explained in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a58ea579-4f71-4384-a9ab-c85937e389c2/can-grow-property-is-not-working-in-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices) article.

Lots of ways to address bleed over into another page, however the one I rely on most is taking a little bit from the margins, it's in the report properties page along with page orientation. You can also change the orientation from portrait to landscape to get a lot of extra horizontal room.

The final and probably the least best practices option I use is to change the paper size in the report properties. It will make it look like it's one page, and most print drivers have shrink to fit page enabled by default, so users generally won't notice. GL and let me know if you have any questions.